# Open chrome console with selenium

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium

I'm trying to open chrome console through selenium and C# binding.
So far I've tried using the actions api like so:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(_driver);
builder.KeyDown(Keys.LeftControl).KeyDown(Keys.LeftShift).SendKeys("p");
```

It doesn't work. What is the right way of doing so?

Comment: I want to use it when I take snapshots with selenium so I can record if there was any errors showing in the console

Comment: I ran the google search on it before coming here. It shows that only Java has this capabilities, not C#. I'm trying to find a workaround by being to just open the console explicitly and taking a snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you did a typo. CTRL+SHIFT+i combination opens chrome dev tools not CTRL+SHIFT+p.

Also you can press F12 to do the same.